# Concatenating composite keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to join 2 tables (employee and student) using inner join and fetch the matching records. I have 3 primary keys `name, age, address`. I am using the following query.

```sql
SELECT 
    a.name,b.name,a.age,b.age,a.salary,b.salary,a.address,b.address 
FROM
    employee a 
INNER JOIN 
    student b ON a.name = b.name AND a.age = b.age AND a.address = b.address 
WHERE 
    (a.name = b.name OR a.age = b.age OR a.address = b.address)
```

Is there any way I can concat the primary keys without using `AND` in the `ON` condition ?

How can the count of matching value for each column be fetched?

Can I write the query using `CASE WHEN` statement?

Comment: "I have 3 primary keys" So each name, each age &each address is unique? Maybe you mean you have one PK with 3 columns? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: PS One does not need to know constraints, including PKs, to query. Knowing table meanings is sufficient & necessary. PS You don't clearly say how your result is a function of input. What does "concat[enate] the primary keys" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Bill Karwin's answer is what you need. Just commenting to add that the WHERE clause you have there is not needed, as the join will ensure that condition is already met.

Answer (score 2):

Join syntax has an option for a `USING (...)` clause as an alternative to `ON ...`. See example:

```
select a.name, b.name, a.age, b.age, a.salary, b.salary, a.address, b.address 
from employee a inner join student b 
  using (name, age, address)
```

The meaning of `USING()` is that it assumes (1) that the columns exist with the same name in both tables, and (2) that you want to compare them with `=`, and (3) all columns have to be equal to the column of the same name in the other table, as if you did `AND` between the terms (just like you're doing in your query).

This USING syntax is of course the same as if you had done the longer syntax with `ON ... AND ... AND ...` like you did. Logically, they're the same. But USING allows you to write the query a little more briefly.

The other downside of USING is that it doesn't use qualified columns like *table*.*column*. So if you had done a join with a third table, and that table also had some columns with names in common, it would become inclear which tables you want to join.